Monolog - each line of log is logged as a new entry
"monolog/monolog": "^2.0"
All of the logging statements are logged as different entries.

sample log :

{
    "message": "http:\/\/docker.for.mac.localhost:1000",
    "context":  
        {
            "$a": "val_a",
            "$b": val_b,
            "$c": val_c,
            "$d": val_d,
        }
    "level": 200,
    "level_name": "INFO",
}

Logged as :
log 1 : "message": "http:\/\/docker.for.mac.localhost:1000",
log 2 : "$a": "val_a",
log 3 : "$b": val_b,
log 4 : "$c": val_c,
log 5 : "$d": val_d,



Ok? So what's your question? Where is the code that's actually creating your logs?

By default, Splunk treats each line of data as a separate event.  However, you can override that using settings in a props.conf file.  It's a Best Practice to have props.conf settings for every sourcetype ingested.
These props should help.  Install them on the indexers and heavy forwarders (if any).
[mysourcetype]
# Break events prior to "message", assuming this is always first
LINE_BREAKER = ([\r\n]+)\{"message
# No timestamp is seen in the events so assign the current time
DATETIME_CONFIG = current
SHOULD_LINEMERGE = false
KV_MODE = json

